# Failure in React Native Build: Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am encountering an issue while attempting to build my React Native project. The build process fails with the following error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-reanimated:androidJdkImage'.
       > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
          > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/zeeshanahmad/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
             > Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/zeeshanahmad/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/393400499b2af28f59d755a5f301569b/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/zeeshanahmad/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/393400499b2af28f59d755a5f301569b/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}
```

I have provided the relevant portion of my package.json file below:

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.12",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.10",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3"
```

It seems to be related to the react-native-reanimated package, specifically during the compilation phase (compileDebugJavaWithJavac). I have tried updating both the React Native and react-native-reanimated packages to their latest versions (0.73.3 and ^3.7.0, respectively), but the issue persists.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: did you try npx jetify ?

Comment: Can you try downgrading to 2.4.1 for react-native-reanimated. I faced this issue and certainly it was because of v3 for reanimated.

Comment: @ko100v.d yes i tried

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.73.3'
    }
}
```

to your android/build.gradle file.
See [react-native-reanimated#3743](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3743) for an explanation.